# error occurs when using ngFor - Angular 4

Tags: angular

error occurs when using ngFor - Angular 4

Would anyone know how to tell why this error is being displayed on the console when I perform the function

The data is being displayed, however this error is still shown

```
empresas = <Empresa> {};

  constructor(private service: Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getEmpresas().subscribe((res) => {
        this.empresas = res
    })
  }
```

Template

```
<tr *ngFor="let empresa of empresas">
            <td>
              {{ empresa.created_at }}
            </td>
            <td>
              {{ empresa.nome }}
            </td>
            <td class="text-center">
              {{ empresa.protocolo }}
            </td>
            <td class="text-right">
              <a [routerLink]="['/resultado']">Explorar resultado</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
```

> HistoricoComponent.html:37 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ
>   supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only
>   supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
>       at NgForOf.webpackJsonp.../../../common/@angular/common.es5.js.NgForOf.ngOnChanges
>   (common.es5.js:1681)
>       at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.es5.js:10833)
>       at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.es5.js:12332)
>       at checkAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:12271)
>       at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.es5.js:13132)
>       at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.es5.js:13073)
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (HistoricoComponent.html:37)
>       at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:13058)
>       at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12238)
>       at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12603)

service

```
getEmpresas(): Observable<any> {
        const headers = new Headers();
        return this.http.get(`${MEAT_API}/empresas`,
            new ResponseOptions({headers: headers}))
            .map(response => response.json())

    }
```

Comment: can you show the service method that is called does it return a array or objects have you called `res.json()` in http service

Comment: Because ngFor iterates only through array items, as I can see you have object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this error is that your iterating over the variable which is not iteratable.
That's the reason `ngFor` is failing,   make sure empresas is array of `Empresa`, try consoling the `res` coming from the API to see if it's any array of `Empresa` objects. The error describes itself.

> NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Answer (score 0):

When your data of `getEmpresas` returns, the value of res is an Object `{}`

```
this.service.getEmpresas().subscribe((res) => {
    this.empresas = res
})
```

The `*ngFor` directive cannot iterate over Objects (unless you're using a KeysPipe). So either have `getEmpresas()` return an array or create said KeysPipe.

example:

```
import {PipeTransform, Pipe} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: 'KeysPipe'
})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
*ngFor="let empresa of empresas | KeysPipe"
{{empresa.key}} {{empresa.value}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assigned the response value of `getEmpresas()` is an object ,and `*ngFor` is unable to iterate an object that's why you have to declare an array, declare empresas: any=[]` as an empty array.

`this.service.getEmpresas().subscribe(res=>this.empresas=res);`

In the template you can traverse the array using `*ngFor` like

```
<tr *ngFor="let empresa of empresas">
>     <td>
>         {{ empresa.created_at }}
>     </td>
>     <td>
>         {{ empresa.nome }}
>     </td>
>     <td class="text-center">
>         {{ empresa.protocolo }}
>     </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
empresas : any = [];
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.